# hide directory in rails project

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have create a new directory with

```
        FileUtils.mkdir_p 'backupFiles' unless File.exists?('backupFiles')
```

how ever i like this folder to be hidden from CL and within the text editor visualisation of the rails project.
Any hints or advise how to do so?
and if the folder is hidden would it still be accessible by my program ? (e.g. with `FileUtils.cp_r "./app", "backupFiles/"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This will be hard to answer correctly without any clarification on what you mean by "hidden" (I would have asked that in a comment, but reputation you know). I'll try anyway.*

What I understand is that your application creates a directory in your app directory that you don't want to see.

If you don't want to see it in the Finder/Nautilus/Windows Explorer, then the easiest way should be to name the directory beginning with period. For your example that would translate to:

`FileUtils.mkdir_p '.backupFiles' unless File.exists?('.backupFiles')`

This wouldn't affect the accessibility of that folder via the commandline or your app in any way. (Accept that it's name starts with a period obviously)

Comment: the folder backupFiles should not be visable via CL nor within the project via text editor

Answer (score 0):

Maybe that might be possible using SELinux Extended Security Attributes but it sounds pretty hard to implement.

Take a look at this:

https://superuser.com/questions/738392/completely-hide-files-on-linux